# Is it possible to read only once in elastic?

Tags: go, elasticsearch, multiple-instances

Is it possible to read-only once in elastic?

Assume I have 4 microservices which reads by timestamp, assuming four microservice has same query and timestamp as a query param. What I am trying to achieve is if any microservice read it then another service shouldn't be reading it again.

Kind of implementing Kafka stream feature, registering multiple listeners on the same query.
Is there any way to achieve this? or any common API gateway?
Microservice is in GOlang ( multi-instance)
I am open for work round, we own other services which pushes data to ES.

Comment: "What I am trying to achieve is if any microservice read it then another service shouldn't be reading it again." This is a little confusing. Do you mean if 1 instance of your microservice reads, then none of the other 3 instances should read? Or do you mean if any of 4 microservice instances read, then no other instances of a different service should read?

Comment: There is nothing like this. But Elasicsearch provides scroll API where you will Scroll id for each search which is basically different for each page. You can use a cache like Redis where you will keep scroll Id, and make reads as an atomic operation which is provided by any caching mechanism. This way you can en ensure that once instance of service will consume unique results.

Comment: @ShaharZ I meant,1 instance of microservice reads, then none of the other 3 instances should read it again.